# Can you loop on a single file with SSIS?

Tags: sql, .net, file, ssis, vsam

I have a EBCDIC (Mainframe) VSAM file without any carriage return.  It is like a million characters long.
With SSIS, could I loop on the file's single line and add a carriage return each time I hit the SIN of the first record type?  (record control type starts with 90)

I have not found any doc on this particular function or if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VSAM or what the SIN token is but you should be able to use a normal flatfile connection but change the new line identifier from carriage return to the SIN. The default end of line token is "{CR}{LF}"

The flat file connection would then treat the SIN's as carriage returns and align your file accordingly

Here is my "VSAM" file with SIN as the carriage return token

[image: VSAM]

Create a flatfile source and set the column header row delimiter token to SIN

[image: Connection]

Next set the row delimiter to SIN

[image: RowDelimiter]

Hit refresh columns to align everything

[image: All done]